# Python, Scapy and Netfilterqueue only intercepts HTTP packets from clients to servers

Tags: python, http, iptables, scapy

I am trying to code a python script that intercepts all HTTP requests that comes to the eth0 interface on my Linux machine.

I can only see the HTTP packets that are sent from the clients to the servers (eg. 192.168.1.201 -> 151.101.1.69) but I never see HTTP packets that are sent from the servers to the clients (eg. 151.101.1.69 -> 192.168.1.201)...

Here is the full python script...

When run, it only passes on the following condition :

```
if http_packet[TCP].dport == 80:
```

And it nevers passes on the following condition :

```
if http_packet[TCP].sport == 80:
```

Thanks !

```
# apt-get install build-essential python-dev libnetfilter-queue-dev
# pip install NetfilterQueue
# sudo apt-get install python-netfilterqueue
# iptables -F
# iptables -F -t nat
# iptables -I FORWARD -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0

from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue
import scapy.all as scapy
import re
import os

from scapy.layers.inet import IP, TCP

os.system("echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward")
os.system("iptables -F")
os.system("iptables -F -t nat")
os.system("iptables -A FORWARD -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0")

ip_src = ""
ip_dst = ""


def print_and_accept(packet):
    global ip_src, ip_dst, dst_port, src_port
    http_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())

    if http_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw) and http_packet.haslayer(TCP):
        if IP in http_packet:
            ip_src = http_packet[IP].src
            ip_dst = http_packet[IP].dst

            print(ip_src + " -> " + ip_dst)

            if http_packet[TCP].dport == 80:
                print(ip_src + " -> " + ip_dst + " ** client to server **")
                load = http_packet[scapy.Raw].load
                print(load)
                load = re.sub("Accept-Encoding:.*?\\r\\n", "", load)

            if http_packet[TCP].sport == 80:
                print(ip_src + " -> " + ip_dst + " ** server to client **")
                load = http_packet[scapy.Raw].load
                print(load)
                load = re.sub("Accept-Encoding:.*?\\r\\n", "", load)

    packet.accept()


nf_queue = NetfilterQueue()
nf_queue.bind(0, print_and_accept)
try:
    nf_queue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    os.system("iptables -F")
    os.system("iptables -F -t nat")
    print("Gettin' out")

nf_queue.unbind()
```

Comment: Hi & welcome to Stackoverflow. Please focus your question on a single issue: saying "it doesn't work, here's my full code" won't be of much help. What is your platform? What part breaks (Python? iptables?) what have you tried?..... You might want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , happy hacking !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the "arpspoof" command that was issued before launching this script.
It is the arpspoof command that is creating the filter for the network packets to intercept.